# Close Dialog with Prism Region Manager

Tags: wpf, mvvm, prism

I have a WPF/PRISM application in which I opened a window using the following code:

```
RegionManager.RequestBlockingDialogNavigate(MyViewModel);
```

How do I close that window without using code behind?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I could achieved my goal doing something else. Basically I just pass the whole window as a parameter of the CloseCommand and close it from the ViewModel.

```
<Button Content="Close" Command="{Binding CloseCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=MyWindow}" />
```

And in the View Model, I just did this:

```
    public DelegateCommand<Window> CloseCommand { get;  private set;} 
    public MyViewModel()
    {
        CloseCommand = new DelegateCommand<Window>(Close);
    }
    public void Close(Window window)
    {
        window.Close();
    }
```

I thought there was something in PRISM to do it. I haven't found anything so far.

Thanks

Comment: That's a violation of MVVM pattern. ViewModels can't have references to Views

Comment: That's why I'm asking for a way to do it in PRISM

Answer (score 0):

You could also try this,

```
<Button Content="Close" Command="{Binding CloseCommand}"  />

public DelegateCommand CloseCommand { get;  private set;} 
public MyViewModel()
{
    CloseCommand = new DelegateCommand(()=>
    {
          foreach (Window window in Application.Current.Windows)
                {
                    if (window is DialogView)//your window type come here
                    {
                        window.Close();
                    }                  }                                                                                        

    });
}
```

This will not work if window was shown with .ShowDialog();

or instead of foreach, this where dialog view is your window

```
Application.Current.Windows.OfType<DialogView>().FirstOrDefault().Close();
```